# Dummy variables in hedonic regression

Tags: regression, econometrics, categorical-encoding

I've been looking into this for quite some time, but unfortunately couldn't figure it out myself. I have some data on real estate transactions, both houses and apartments, and want to do a regression across the entire data set.

Let's assume the following variables

- log(price): applicable for all housing units
- log(living_area): applicable for all housing units
- log(lot): only applicable for houses
- log(rent): only applicable for apartments
- type_apartment: vector with 1 for apartment and 0 for house
- type_house: vector with 1 for house and 0 for apartment

Regarding the data structure: price and living_area show continuous variables across the entire length of the vector. area_lot only has values in case it's a house and 0 otherwise, vice versa rent only has values for apartments and is 0 for houses.

The simplified regression looks like this.

```
fit.all <- lm(log(price) ~
     +log(living_area)
     +log(lot):type_house
     +log(rent):type_apartment
     +type_house) #added variable to capture effect of unit being a house; base case is apartment
```

I'm not 100% sure the above approach is correct. As example, if one of the units entering the regression is a house, then the corresponding value in the dummy vector type_apartment will be 0. Hence, the value stored for rent should not be considered (as houses don't come with rents).

So far I've tried the "*" and ":" operators as well as using e.g. ":factor(type_apartment) as dummy term, but with no success.

I guess there's a simple answer for this, but I couldn't find it. If you could help me out with this one it would be greatly appreciated.